# Can not reconnect to NX session

Tags: gnome, nx

I'm no NX expert.
My NXServer (NOMachine) has two running (GNOME) sessions and I can not reconnect to them ?
Even if I stop/start the nxserver daemon, the nxssh sessions are still there.
`nxserver --shutdown also fails`

Before I do a hard kill, I wanted to know if & how to reconnect them or stop them gracefully.

**ADDITION OF LOGS**

7:46 is when I failed to connect.
11:57 is when I decide to hard kill

```
Session: Suspending session at 'Thu Jun  9 00:08:21 2011'.
Info: Watchdog running with pid '29027'.
Info: Waiting the watchdog process to complete.
Session: Session suspended at 'Thu Jun  9 00:08:22 2011'.
Session: Resuming session at 'Thu Jun  9 07:45:37 2011'.
Info: Proxy running in server mode with pid '5038'.
Info: Waiting for connection from '127.0.0.1' on port '5026'.
Info: Aborting the procedure due to signal '1'.
Session: Display failure detected at 'Thu Jun  9 07:46:53 2011'.
Session: Suspending session at 'Thu Jun  9 07:46:53 2011'.
Session: Session suspended at 'Thu Jun  9 07:46:53 2011'.
Session: Terminating session at 'Fri Jun 10 11:57:06 2011'.
Session: Session terminated at 'Fri Jun 10 11:57:07 2011'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful to check log files for errors or anything?
If you find anything post them here so we have more information to work with.

Hard killing it wont be a problem but always check logs first.

Comment: good idea, just came too late I had to hard kill those tasks.